# Perl While Loop to send HTTP Requests

Tags: perl, http, http-post, http-get

I need help writing a script to send 25 requests then close the socket and start a new one.

This is what I have so far:

```
while ($count<25) {
    $count++;
    die "Could not create socket: $!\n" unless $sock;
    print $sock "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    print $sock "Host: $host \r\n";
    print $sock "Cookie: $rand \r\n\r\n";
    print while <$sock>;
    close($sock);
};
```

So after 25 requests, it closes the socket and starts another one (kind of like a `goto` command).

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using a module for this purpose, such as [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3A%3AUserAgent). It will most likely make your life much easier than using sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have some kind of (foreach or while) loop

```
while (...) {
   ... Uses $socket ...
}
```

and you want to use the same $socket for 25 passes, then switch to a new one. So simply count the number of passes, and update $socket if the number of elapsed passes is evenly divisible by 25.

```
my $socket;
my $count = 0;
while (...) {
   if (($count++ % 25) == 0) {
      $socket = ...;
   }

   ... Uses $socket ...
}
```

Comment: I actually wanted something that goes like this : 1)Open Socket, 2)Send 25 Requests, 3)Close Socket, 4)Loop

Comment: @Mohamed Gamrah, You always send the same 25 requests? Loop unconditionally (as opposed to repeat for each element of a list, a specific number of times, or until a condition is true)? `while (1) { my $socket = ...; ... send requests ...; }`